# date changes while parsing in windows phone for different languages

Tags: windows-phone-7, datetime, localization

I have come across a strange problem. MY app has been localized to support 5 languages.
It is a calendar sort of app, and i have an option of writing notes for a particular date.
So when I change my language settings to Russian,  enter a note on a date, eg 1/3/2012 and on 6/3/2012. This date and note is stored in an `IsolatedStorageFile` and i exit the app.

Now, I change my language settings to english, and the notes are stored in 3/1/2012 and 3/6/2012. The month and date are reversed !! :(

This is how i write the notes to the file

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = storagefile.OpenFile("NotesFile", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream);

    for (int i = 0; i < m_noteCount; i++)
    {
        writer.Write(m_arrNoteDate[i].ToShortDateString());
        writer.Write(" ");
        writer.Write(m_arrNoteString[i]);
        writer.WriteLine("~`");
    }
    writer.Close();
}
```

Reading is from file is done like this

```
if (notes.Substring(i, 1) == " ")
{
      m_arrNoteString[count] = notes.Substring(i + 1);
      string temp = notes.Substring(0, i);
      m_arrNoteDate[count] = DateTime.Parse(temp);
      count++;
      nextCharacter = (char)reader.Read();
      notes = "";
      break;
}
```

the parser reads date in a format according to language the device is set to? Any work arounds?

Alfah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the conversion between dates and strings (and vice versa) uses the current culture. For your purpose, since you are not converting to/from strings for the purpose of displaying dates to the user but to persist them, you should make your logic independent of the current culture by specifying a given culture. And the invariant culture is your best best.

So replace this:

```
writer.Write(m_arrNoteDate[i].ToShortDateString());
```

With this:

```
writer.Write(m_arrNoteDate[i].ToString("d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

And replace this:

```
m_arrNoteDate[count] = DateTime.Parse(temp);
```

With this:

```
m_arrNoteDate[count] = DateTime.Parse(temp, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thanks, Could you tell me what "d" is?

Comment: You're welcome! About the "d", it's the short date format pattern that is recognized by ToString(). The MSDN documentation for ToShortDateString() says this: "The return value is identical to the value returned by specifying the "d" standard DateTime format string with the ToString(String) method". Since ToShortDateString doesn't allow you to pass in a culture, in this case you're stuck with ToString.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Parse` has an overloaded method where you can pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to read it independently of region settings. Also, you need to save value accordingly too.

Also, look at `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`. You can set specific culture to application globally.

Answer (score 1):

Use m_arrNoteDate[i].ToString("d", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) when writing date to have it independent of the thread culture.